# How to Fill in the Area Underneath an ASP.Net Spline Chart Control with a Color?

Tags: asp.net, controls, charts, sparklines

I have an ASP.Net Chart Control of ChartType "Spline", one ChartArea and one Series (it's a sparkline). I was just wondering if anyone out there knew how I could color the area underneath the line - I can't seem to find the property that allows me to do this without coloring the entire background.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a chart with a ChartType of Area to achieve this type of look (similar to google analytics). I have tried it and it does work although i'm not sure how you might get the line to be one particular colour and the area underneath to be a second colour?

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/MSWinWebChart/thread/981cc4df-2b23-4557-8d89-0b45d553fecc/